# iOS - NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate does not update the table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've a UITableView with following code in lifecycle:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [UserModel fetchAllSortedBy:@"fullName" ascending:YES withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self];
    [self updatePredicate];    
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
}
```

and in NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

The method [self updatePredicate]:

```
- (void) updatePredicate {
    NSPredicate *messageFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"address != nil"];
    self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = messageFilter;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

To simulate the change into CoreDate I've added a simple UIBarButton event:

```
- (IBAction)didChangeSomething:(id)sender {
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        UserDAO *userDAO = [[UserDAO alloc] initWithContext:localContext];
        UserModel *userDB = [userDAO getUserById:@"a3535ee6-645a-4f6e-9970-4df65120353e"];
        userDB.address = userDB.address == nil ? @"Testing" : nil;
        [localContext saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    }]; 
}
```

Some additional info:

- The UserModel is the CoreData Entity
- The UserDAO is a my class that invoke this method

  return [UserModel findFirstByAttribute:@"uid" withValue:@"a3535ee6-645a-4f6e-9970-4df65120353e" inContext:self.context];

I've this strange behaviour:

1. If I open my UITableViewController for first time (when address field is nil) no rows is shown, then I click on my UIBarButton and nothing happens. (But in my Sqlite file I can see the real change of address in "Testing").
2. If I close my UITableViewController and I re-open it, I can see the entry on TableView. Now if I click on UIBarButton the table updates correctly, adding and removing the entry more times.

Why I've this behaviour? What's happening? Why the TableView wasn't updated when I change the value of field "Address"?

EDIT 1:
If I change:

```
UserDAO *userDAO = [[UserDAO alloc] initWithContext:localContext];
```

with

```
UserDAO *userDAO = [[UserDAO alloc] initWithContext:[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread]];
```

all works fine.

Comment: What is `UserDAO`,`UserModel`,`userDB.address`? Please clear your code (remove code lines which are not related). To create `NSManagedObject` object, try `MR_createEntity` method

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm always using the MR_createEntity method to create entity with MagicalRecord. I don't understand why at first time when address is nil, if I change this value nothing happens (updating with click UIBarButton). The second time, when address is != nil, the change of field works correctly (the table is correctly).

Comment: Make sure you created new object into right `NSManagedObjectContext`. Try this: replace `userDB.address = userDB.address == nil ? @"Testing" : nil;` by `userDB.address = @"testing";`

Comment: I've tried, but nothing change.

Comment: It's a problem of ManagedObjectContext, but I can't able to fix it...

Comment: What answer? I haven't solved yet...